# input-group not expanding to fill 100% - bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am experimenting with Bootstrap 3 and while creating a form, I ran into a simple issue. I have a label and an input textbox but for some reason I cannot get the textbox to automatically fill 100% of the available width. If I force width:100% then it overflows into the next row. Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I have pasted a screenshot as well as a fiddle. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="row row-top-buffer row-bottom-buffer">
    <div class="col-md-3 row-label">Title:</div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" placeholder="title">
    </div>
</div>

.row-top-buffer {
    padding-top: 21px;
}

.row-bottom-buffer {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.row-label {
    font: 14px "OpenSans-Bold";
    color: #4d4d4d;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.input-group .form-control.input-text {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .1 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .1 );
    color: #566266;
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chicagosky/VyvLR/)

[image: screenshot showing css and output]

Comment: I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyvLR/1/). Just take a good look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms and see how they do it there!

Comment: Maybe a silly question but I would like the label and the text input side by side like I have demoed in my screenshot. Is there any way to do this? Your example in the fiddle has the label and text input in different lines. Thanks for the link - will see if I can extract something from there as well in the interim

Comment: Ok - found it - i could use horizontal forms to do this. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the form-horizontal.  See the Form Horizontal section under http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms.

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/5wQUy/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 section">
            <div class="row section-header">
                    <h2>Edit details</h2>
    
            </div>
            <!-- .section-header -->
            <div class="row row-top-buffer row-bottom-buffer form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-xs-3 control-label row-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-xs-3 control-label row-label">Full Name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="name" placeholder="full name" />
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="streetaddress" class="col-xs-3 control-label row-label">Street Address</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="streetaddress" placeholder="street address" />
                    </div>
                </div>                     
            </div>
            <div class="row section-footer"> <a href="#">[Reset]</a>
    
            </div>
            <!-- .section-header -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also added 15px padding left/right on the form-horizontal class.

Comment: Thank you - now my next experiment is to figure out how to nest inline-form inside horizontal-form

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem a number of times.

Beware that the input, select, textarea elements do not have the CCS set a default max-width for input fields.   It over-rides the 100% and you drive yourself nuts trying to figure out why.

Comment: OMG! I owe you life!